# Drupal 7 admin can't upload images, but all other users can

Tags: 7, media, files

I'm experiencing a very strange error and I can't figure out what's causing it. I have a drupal 7 website and all users and roles can upload images without any issues, except user 1, the administrator. When I try to upload an image as user 1 to ANY content type or delete an already existing image it freezes or returns this:

"An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the", the strange part is admin has all the permissions and I disabled the admin menu and other modules that are unique to being user 1. Any ideas? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: I added the administrator role to a user that was currently able to upload images and now they too can't upload images to any content type and in the upload progress bar it freezes at around 62%, so it's something to do with the role. I'm going to try turning off virtually all contributed modules and turn them on one by one.

Comment: I disabled virtually all the contributed modules I was using and I still have the same problem. Going to try and create a new role, give it all the permissions, assign it to a different user and see if that works.

Comment: i get this error too , how did you solve it ?

Comment: Even though, this answer is super old, it became a popular question, so it needs an update. I removed per user quotas and also discovered there was some code in a custom module similar to what's in this module https://www.drupal.org/project/upload_qc that was overriding the default file size on all file fields. So I had multiple things causing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you reached the upload limit for user 1, are you using IMCE ?

Comment: Seconded. You have to be careful with per user quota in IMCE.